# JSP Water Mark code is not working

Tags: jsp

I have created the code but the error says that "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!". Please help to resolve.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" import="java.awt.AlphaComposite,java.awt.Color,java.awt.Font,
     java.awt.Graphics,java.awt.Graphics2D,java.awt.Image,java.awt.image.BufferedImage,java.io.File,java.io.FileOutputStream,
     javax.imageio.ImageIO,javax.swing.ImageIcon,com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec,com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGEncodeParam,
     com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder" %>
<%


try
{
  Font font;
  File _file = new File("images/1.jpg");
  Image src = ImageIO.read(_file);
  int width = src.getWidth(null);
  int height = src.getHeight(null);
  System.out.println("X = "+width+" and Y = "+height);
  BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
  g.drawImage(src, 0, 0, width, height, null);
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));

  g.drawString("www.somelink.com",  5, height - (new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20)).getSize() / 2 - 5);
  g.dispose();

  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("after.jpg");
  JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(fout);
  encoder.encode(image);
  fout.close();
} catch (Exception ee)
{
  out.println("Error Occurred : "+ee);
}
%>
```

I am unable to solve this exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike console programs, web applications in Java do not assume the working directory. You have to give it a full path. In a JSP you can use `application.getRealPath("/")` to get the base path of the application:

```
File _file = new File(application.getRealPath("/")+"images/1.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks but now i am getting "Error Occurred : java.io.FileNotFoundException: after.jpg (Access is denied)"

Comment: @Aayush Its the same issue.